# Laravel: Two model route bind WITHOUT relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models: `Type` and `Category`. I want to make a route that must contain one slug of each.

That's my route:

```php
Route::get('/route-{type:slug}-{category:slug}', 'Controller@typeAndCategory');
```

And in my controller:

```php
public function typeAndCategory(Type $bikeType, Category $category) {}
```

According to [Laravel's doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#implicit-model-binding-scoping):

> When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a **NESTED** route parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the nested model by its parent using conventions to guess the **relationship** name on the parent.

But in my case, those two models haven't relation.

The question is: how can I tell this to Laravel?

Comment: The Laravel doc means you can do `/route/{type}/{category}` and laravel can determine if category belongs to type. But it's not necessary to have that relation fixed, you can just add well have unrelated items. I don't think laravel can determine the routes based on what you want, although I haven't tried it. You could do `/{routeWithSlugs}` and have a `$routeWithSlugs` variable cone into your function, and paste the string yourself.

Comment: I've tried it and don't work. I would like to use the model bind feature, not manually find the register.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but i just came across the same issue
and you have to use
->withoutScopedBindings(); to your route

so it would look like

```
Route::get('/route-{type:slug}-{category:slug}', 'Controller@typeAndCategory')->withoutScopedBindings();
```

hopefully This helps anyone !